# Не запускается Windows 10 с установочной флешки

Tags: windows-10, linux-mint

На установочной флешке у меня образ Windows 10, сама ОС на компьютере - Linux Mint. Когда через Boot запускаю флешку, открывается не установщик виндовс, а меню GNU GRUB, с пунктами:
-Linux Mint 20.3 Cinnamon
-Дополнительные параметры для Linux Mint 20.3 Cinnamon

Comment: Как создавали загрузочную флешку?

Answer (score 0):

Забыл ответить, проблема решена, я просто использовал другую программу для создания загрузочной флешки (не помню какую, специально с Linux на Windows)